# Reading data from a CSV and writing unique rows to external CSVs

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read read data from a CSV and write it to a new CSV splitting up the data into multiple files where the email address ($row[14]) is unique in each file. The CSV that I'm reading from is already ordered by email address.  The loop is working correctly here except that the files that are being created all contain only one row.  How can I modify this to write rows into each file that only contain a unique email address.

```
<?php
 $file = fopen("yahrzeit-4.csv","r");
 $x=1;

 while  ( $row = fgetcsv( $file, ";" ) ) { 

 if ($file) {
 if ($email = $row[14] == $email) {

    $filename = 'mailchimp'.$x.'.csv';  

    $fpR = fopen($filename, 'w');   

    $dataR = array( $row[2], 
                $row[3], 
                $row[14], 
                $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
                );

    $email = $row[14];  $x++;   

}
    else { 

    $x=1;

    $fp = fopen('mailchimp.csv', 'w');  

    $data = array ( $row[2], 
                $row[3], 
                $row[14], 
                $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
              );

    }

    $email = $row[14];

}
fputcsv($fpR, $dataR);      
fputcsv($fp, $data);

}       

fclose($fp);
fclose($fpR);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it looks like you're trying to create a CSV file containing the records from another CSV file. The exception is if you find duplicate email addresses you want these to go into a different file for each duplicate maintaining as few files as you can as long as the addresses are unique in each?

I obviously haven't checked this as I don't have your data but this should hopefully do what you're after, splitting non-unique email addresses into the next available file (for that address).

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("yahrzeit-4.csv","r");
    $addresses = array(); //This will hold counters for each address
    $fp = fopen('mailchimp.csv', 'w'); //This is the first list
    $fp2 = array(); //This will hold handles for each subsequent csv, 1 for each non-unique address (although it may hold more than one address unique to the file)

    if($file) {
        while  ( $row = fgetcsv( $file, ";" ) ) { //Read file
            if(isset($addresses[$row[14]])) { //Email has been found before at least once
                $targetfile = $addresses[$row[14]]; //Check the counter to find the next csv to write to for this particular address
                if(!isset($fp2[$targetfile])) { //Check if it has already been opened
                    $fp2[$targetfile] = fopen('mailchimp'.$targetfile.'.csv', 'w'); //If not open it and store it in the array of file handles for later use
                }

                $dataR = array( 
                    $row[2], 
                    $row[3], 
                    $row[14], 
                    $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                    $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                    jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
                );

                fputcsv($fp2[$targetfile], $dataR); //Write data to this file handle
                $addresses[$row[14]]++; //Increment counter for this email address so the next write will go into the next sequential file.

            } else { //This is the standard write if the address is not a duplicate
                $data = array (
                    $row[2], 
                    $row[3], 
                    $row[14], 
                    $row[6] . ' ' . $row[7] . ' ' . $row[8], 
                    $row[11] . ' ' . $row[10] . ', ' . $row[12], 
                    jdtogregorian ( jewishtojd($Hebmonth, $row[6], 5774 ))
                );

                fputcsv($fp, $data);
                $addresses[$row[14]] = 1;
            }
        }

        foreach($fp2 as $handle) { //Close all handles
            fclose($handle);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given for this line: fputcsv($fp, $dataR);

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what happened to my response but there was a typo in the above. I have edited my answer and it should hopefully be right now.

Comment: The error is gone, but its still only putting one row into each CSV.

Comment: I have created a basic test at my end and it looks to be working now. I had missed a "2" in my isset check. I've also removed a couple of other things that were not necessary or may have caused trouble.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  I'm trying to add another check for duplicates in here but am having a hard time understanding how this actually works..  I need to add another check after the unique addresses to also check for unique names and exclude duplicates.

Comment: @MG1 I have added additional comments to better explain every line. If you were wanting to use the address as well as the name as a combined unique identifier then you could simply concatenate them together to form a unique string and use that as the key of the $addresses array instead. Instead of $addresses[$row[14]] it would be $addresses[$row[14].$row[2]] (assuming $row[2] is your name field).